# Accessing LIst of Businesses at GoogleMaps

Tags: google-places-api

If you go to www.google.com/maps and enter an address with a business at it (such as 100 Congress Ave, Austin, TX) you get a return page which includes "At this address" and then lists some businesses there.

Not all addresses have this section (see 100 S Congress Ave, Austin, TX).

I'm using google places API and would like to access this info.  When I compare the results for 100 Congress Ave, Austin, TX between the Google Places API and www.google.com/maps, I don't get the same results.

Anybody know how to get this list of business via the Google API's which shows up on www.google.com/maps?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a [Places API Text Search request](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#TextSearchRequests) with `what's at` in from of the address in the `query` parameter:

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=what's%20at%20100%20Congress%20Ave,%20Austin,%20TX&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=what%27s%20at%20100%20Congress%20Ave,%20Austin,%20TX&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY)